# Dijkstra with Airports and Roads

Tags: c++, algorithm, networking, graph, dijkstra

I'm thinking on how I might solve a problem to link cities. I need to decide in which ones I would build airports or roads.
I imagined that a graph could represent this situation. The vertices would be the cities with a weight symbolizing the price of an airport and the edges the roads with also a weight. The goal is to connect all cities to the network, minimizing the total cost of the works.
I think an adaptation of Dijkstra algoritm would give me the cheapest price, where the total weight of a vertice is his base cost plus the edge cost.
I'm in reasoning phase so any tip or reference is grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is about Minimum Spanning Tree question...
So,kruskal or prim algorithm is ok...
Dijkstra is about the smallest path when you know starting point..
Wish this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot i didn't know them!
How do I represente cities with airports?